# Docker и облачные хостинги

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, digitalocean

Столкнулся с проблемой на `AWS`, когда при частых сборках проектов на слабых сервачках в докере исчерпываются CPU лимиты и они просто лежат, лежат настолько, что отклик от команды `ls`- секунды, и нужно ждать определенное количество времени (часы) для повторной сборки или других операций.

Интересует везде ли это в облачных сервисах (например `Digital Ocean`) такие условия. Неужели нельзя взять за 5$ долларов маленький сервак в месяц, и собирать в докере 1 проект хоть 100 раз в день? Это ведь не такая большая нагрузка, чтобы бежала какая-то бд с простеньким беком. Подскажите плз.

Comment: Берите за 5$ любой маленький сервак без проблем, непонятно зачем вам вообще сдались все эти AWS и Digital Ocean

Answer (score 1):

Вы, видимо, используете один из 'burstable' инстансов (t2, t3). Они расчитаны на использование CPU ниже определенной отметки, с возможностью использовать процессор выше этой отметки (вплоть до 100%) лишь некоторое время. Во время работы burstable инстансы генерируют CPU-кредиты, которые расходуются при превышении заданного уровня нагрузки CPU. Подробнее об этом написано в документации (англ.): [CPU credits and baseline utilization for burstable performance instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html). Там же можно посмотреть какой уровень производительности ожидается от какого типа инстанса.

Burstable инстанс можно переключить в режим неограниченных кредитов, в таком случае производительность машины не будет падать при окончании кредитов, но за перерасход придется доплатить. Подробнее об этом режиме: [Unlimited mode for burstable performance instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html)

Помимо этого можно взять инстанс без CPU-кредитов, например один из категории [Compute optimised](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#Compute_Optimized), или рассмотреть варианты других провайдеров.

Comment: Надеюсь не сочтут за рекламу, у Oracle Cloud можно получить полностью бесплатный инстанс: https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/#always-free